# Calculator without using more than 1 variable

Tags: java, calculator

```
public class Calculator {
        Double x;
        /*
        * Chops up input on ' ' then decides whether to add or multiply.
        * If the string does not contain a valid format returns null.
        */
        public Double x(String x){
            x.split(" ");
            return new Double(0);
        }

        /*
        * Adds the parameter x to the instance variable x and returns the answer as a Double.
        */
        public Double x(Double x){
                System.out.println("== Adding ==");
                if (x(1).equals("+")){
                x = x(0) + x(2);
                }
                return new Double(0);
        }

        /*
        * Multiplies the parameter x by instance variable x and return the value as a Double.
        */
        public Double x(double x){
                System.out.println("== Multiplying ==");
                if(x(1).equals("x")){
                    x = x(0) * x(2);
                }
                return new Double(0);
        }

}
```

Im trying to split the double entered ("12 + 5") split it using " " and then make it + or x based on the 2nd value and then add or times the results. Thought I could do it with just splitting and times/adding but isn't working.

Comment: Yikes. What exactly are you trying to accomplish by mixing `double`s and `Double`s, particularly in such a remarkably counterintuitive way?

Comment: what is this.. ??? :o

Comment: Did you see that you test `Double.equals(String)` ? This compiles but has no chance to return `true`.

Comment: I don't mean to be unkind, but there really is basically nothing in your code that is not wrong. Start from scratch. Do not reuse any names -- that is, don't have three functions called `x` and also a variable called `x` and also function parameters called `x`.

Comment: Rename your methods. This is like naming a book `Calculator` and the chapters `x`. And your problem statement could be clearer. It's always good to include examples.

Comment: Unfortunately I have to agree with @Ben. The more I look at your code, the more confused I get. Where did you find this?

Comment: `x(0)` is different from `x[0]`. The first is method call, the second is an array position.

Comment: Can you post code indicating how you are calling this class, what the results were, and your expected results?

Comment: If this is an exercice, try to use a `String` instead of a `Double`. If this is rather a real business need, consider using `ScriptEngineManager`.

Comment: Im trying to create a Calculator with just the variables already declared, its a challenge to help learn java but ive hit a wall and what can do i to get turn  if (x(1).equals("+")) into a valid statement

Comment: @user1642671 If you try to eval an expression of form `A+B`, your input is a `String`, not a `Double`. Then, you can use `String.charAt(index)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're properly saving the results of your string split.

```
x.split(" ");
```

returns a String[] with each of the pieces that were separated by " " e.g.

```
String x = "1 x 2";
String[] split = x.split(" ");

split[0] == "1";
split[1] == "x";
split[2] == "2";
```

You could probably benefit from using more descriptive names to your methods and variables.

Something like this would probably work:

```
public class Calculator {
    public static int result;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String expression = args[0];
        String[] terms = expression.split(" ");
        int firstNumber = Integer.parseInt(terms[0]);
        int secondNumber = Integer.parseInt(terms[2]);
        String operator = terms[1];

        switch (operator)
        {
            case "*":
                //multiply them
                break;
            case "+":
                //add them
                break;
            case "-":
                //subtract them
                break;
            case "/":
                //divide them
                break;
        }
    }
}
```